# Store the value objects after joining two PairRDDs in spark

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have two PairRDDs in spark , for eg

> (K1,V1)   and  (K1,V2)

I am trying to join these two RDDs and get the resultant joined RDD as :

> (K1,List(V1,V2))

How can we do this ?

Comment: is there a specific reason you wanted as list ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [cogroup](http://apachesparkbook.blogspot.in/2015/12/cogroup-example.html) for this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Join is performed on pair RDDs.

```
 rdd1.join(rdd2) will give you the result (K1,(V1,V2))
```

If you want values as a List , try below .

```
 rdd1.join(rdd2).mapValues(x=>List(x))
```

Comment: I want to handle two row objects seperately. It's for some data match requirements.

Comment: I am going with cogroup.. thanks aruna kiran for your answer